# Int values from an excel files have a ".0" in the end?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, xlrd

I am using this simple code to extract values from the first column from an excel file:

```
import xlrd

loc = 'location...'

wb = xlrd.open_workbook(loc)
sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
sheet.cell_value(0,0)

for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    print(sheet.cell_value(i,0))
```

The values from that column are:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

However, in python it prints:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
4.0
5.0
```

I need to read it exactly as `1, 2, 3...` not with the `.0` in the last. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming this is what prints the values.

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    print(sheet.cell_value(i,0))
```

It is printing floats, turn em into ints.

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    print(int(sheet.cell_value(i,0)))
```

Say a value in `sheet.nrows` is not an integer try this.

```
for i in range(sheet.nrows):
    try:
        print(int(sheet.cell_value(i,0)))
    except:
        print(sheet.cell_value(i,0))
```

Comment: If ever there are values like `ABC123`? That would turn out to be an error if converted to int. The one with the ints will have a `.0` again

Comment: right. You need to catch that with a try and except. I'll provide an example in a second.